# Property 'defaultProps' does not exist on type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I have a Typescript React class component like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

interface Props {
  bar?: boolean;
}

const defaultProps: Partial<Props> = {
  bar: false,
};

class Foo extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    ...
  }
}

Foo.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default Foo;
```

Here I get the following type error:

```
Property 'defaultProps' does not exist on type 'typeof Foo'.
```

I see 2 solutions to solve this. One is to declare the type on the class like so:

```
class Foo extends Component<Props> {
  static defaultProps: Partial<Props>;

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

The other is to declare the defaultProps inside the class entirely like so:

```
class Foo extends Component<Props> {
  static defaultProps: Partial<Props> = {
    bar: false,
  };

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm using eslint-config-airbnb 18.0.1 and eslint 6.1.0 so both of these solutions throw this eslint error:

`'defaultProps' should be declared outside the class body (react/static-property-placement)`

Is there a way to declare defaultProps outside the class without throwing a type error?

Comment: If you made it a functional component, keeping the defaultProps outside, does it work?

Comment: There is no component call `Image` in your code above

Comment: @MukeshSoni Sorry typo. Fixed in question now.

Comment: eslint is meant to be for ES (JS) isn't it? Typescript has its own linter. This being said most current recommendation is functional components and hooks so if it's a new component maybe that would be an ever better approach

Comment: @apokryfos Typescript are dropping support for TSLint and recommend using ESLint now because it's faster and better maintained.

Comment: Even so, I'd be quite skeptical to use the airbnb set of rules because remember, that set is just what the people at AirBnB thought would be a reasonable default set of rules for their programmers. That will definitely not be appropriate to use if those rules were written having JavaScript in mind.

Answer (score 5):

TS docs say static defaultProps is [the way to go](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#support-for-defaultprops-in-jsx).

Seems weird to add eslint on top of TS, I believe airbnb config is for javascript, not TypeScript.

Comment: Typescript checks types whereas ESLint checks all sorts of formatting and other things (e.g. integration with Prettier). Typescript also seem to be dropping support for TSLint and recommend using ESLint now. Airbnb config is industry standard for React so I wouldn't want to drop industry standard rules because I'm using Typescript instead of JavaScript. It works across my entire application except this 1 rule.

Comment: If eslint works with typescript, that's ok then. Maybe there is a rule for eslint that needs to be disabled? If the presets forbid the recommended use case from official ts docs, something is not clearly ok with the presets

Comment: Good to keep in mind that ecmascript and typescript are different languages. Not just a superset, but literally compiled down to JS. Linting config written for JS will not work in all cases for TS development.

Answer (score 0):

your solution 2 is the best way to handle that case:

```js
class Foo extends Component<Props> {
  static defaultProps: Partial<Props>;

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

---

If you have the opportunity, the best and cleaner IMO would be to refactor your component to functional style:

```js
function Foo({ 
  var1 = 'defaultValue, 
  var2 = 'default2 
}: Props) {
  return <View>...</View>
}
```